# Is there any way to use javascript (jquery) to make an element behave **exactly** as if it was clicked (a unique situation)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make  '`select`'  element to behave as if it was clicked while i click on a completely different divider. Is it possible to make it act as if it was clicked on when its not??

here is my code
http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlerOnDaRoof/B4JUK/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#arrow").click(function () {
        $("#selectCar").click() // I also tried trigger("click");
    });
});
```

So far it didnt work with either `.click();`
nor with the `.trigger("click");`

**Update:**

From what i currently understand the answer is no, you cannot. Although click duplicates the functionality it will not work for certain examples like this one. If anybody knows why this is please post the answer below and i will accept it as best answer. Preferably please include examples for which it will not work correctly.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the trigger(event) function like  `("selector").trigger("click")`

Comment: this does not work as i want the  select element to do exactly the same thing as if it was clicked so open up the options list but it doesnt do that with .trigger("click")

Answer (score 2):

You can call the [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function without arguments, which triggers an artificial click. E.g.:

```
$("selector for the element").click();
```

That will fire jQuery handlers and (I believe) DOM0 handlers as well. <s>I don't think it fires</s> It doesn't fire handlers added via DOM2-style `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` calls, as you can see here: [Live example](http://jsbin.com/uyujev) | [source](http://jsbin.com/uyujev/edit)

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#target").click(function() {
    display("<code>click</code> received by jQuery handler");
  });
  document.getElementById("target").onclick = function() {
    display("<code>click</code> received by DOM0 handler");
  };
  document.getElementById("target").addEventListener(
    'click', 
    function() {
      display("<code>click</code> received by DOM2 handler");
    },
    false
  );

  display("Triggering click");
  $("#target").click();

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});
```

And [here's a version](http://jsbin.com/uyujev/2) ([source](http://jsbin.com/uyujev/2/edit)) using the `onclick="..."` attribute mechanism for the DOM0 handler; it gets triggered that way too.

Also note that it probably won't perform the default action; for instance [this example](http://jsbin.com/uyujev/3) ([source](http://jsbin.com/uyujev/3/edit)) using a link, the link doesn't get followed.

---

If you're in control of the handlers attached to the element, this is usually not a great design choice; instead, you'd ideally make the action you want to take a function, and then *call* that function both when the element is clicked and at any other time you want to take that action. But if you're trying to trigger handlers attached by other code, you can try the simulated click.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
$('#yourElementID').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you added the event listener with jquery you can use .trigger();

$('#my_element').trigger('click');

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can trigger a click on something using:

```
$('#elementID').trigger('click');
```

Have a look at the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

Seeing you jsfiddle, first learn to use this tool.

You selected MooTools and not jQuery. (updated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B4JUK/1/))

Now, triggering a "click" event on a select won't do much.
I guess you want the 2nd select to unroll at the same time as the 1st one.

As far as I know, it's not possible.

If not, try the "change" event on select.

Comment: that is almost exactly what i have in mind. what do you mean by trying the change event on select just $("#select").trigger("change") ??

Comment: @Xitcod13 as I said, making a select open and/or move is not possible (afaik). The change event can allow you to make change the selected `select` element. Of course, you'll need to make a custom handler. `$(selector).change(function(){ ... });`